# wget - how to download all files that only include "480p" using wget from http server?

Tags: shell, wget

I want to download all files from a http server like:
http://dl.mysite.com/files/
and I also want to go inside each folder inside that folder.
But I do want to download only those files that have "480p" in their name.

What is the easiest solution for that using `wget`?

edit:

I want to have that script to be run each night from 2am to 6am to sync those files from that server to my PC.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The following `wget` command should work with the following flags:

```
wget -A "*480p*" -r -np -nc --no-check-certificate -e robots=off http://dl.mysite.com/files/
```

Explanation:

`-A` "*480p*" your pattern

`-r, recursively` recursively look through the folders

`-np, --no-parent` ignore links to a higher directory

`-nc, --no-clobber` If a file is downloaded more than once in the same directory, Wget’s behavior depends on a few options, including ‘-nc’. In certain cases, the local file will be clobbered, or overwritten, upon repeated download. In other cases it will be preserved.

`--no-check-certificate` Don’t check the server certificate against the available certificate authorities.

`-e, --execute command` A command thus invoked will be executed after the commands in *.wgetrc*

`robots=off` robot exclusion

More information on `wget` flags can be found at the official GNU manual page: https://www.gnu.org/software/wget/manual/wget.html

With regards to it being run once per day, you may want to read up on `Cron` jobs. Taken from the documentation page at: https://help.ubuntu.com/community/CronHowto

> A crontab file is a simple text file containing a list of commands meant to be run at specified times. It is edited using the crontab command. The commands in the crontab file (and their run times) are checked by the cron daemon, which executes them in the system background.

So basically you need to put your `wget` command into a file, and set the cron to run this file at the specified time.

Note: Windows does not have a native implementation of `Cron`, but you can achieve the same effect using the *Windows Task Scheduler*.

Comment: how can I tell wget to download to eg "s:\down2\" folder?

Comment: Run the command from inside of that folder, or by using the `-p` flag. This stands for _prefix_ and is the directory where the files will be saved to. e.g. `-P s:\down2\`